# Can someone tell me the difference between AddForce and transform.translate?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, move, rigid-bodies

I am trying to move a gameobject but I found these two most popular functions to move the object. The difference I know between these two is that there is a rigidbody needed in using AddForce but no Rigidbody needed in Transform.translate. I just wanted to make sure that I am using right function for game. Is there anny difference in the functionality of these two function? I am moving a cube over an infinite plane with obstacles in the way. I think rigidbody is needed ofcourse but I want to know what is the use of Transform.translate?

Comment: AddForce adds force.  Translate moves the object.

Comment: As a rule, if you are using a rigidbody, then DO NOT use translate - simply use the physics (ie, add force ......... OR, set the velocity)

Comment: Here are clear explanation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tNtOcDryKv4

Comment: @caxapexac,, that was a very nice video, got clear a lot !!! thanks

Answer (score 7):

**transform.translate:**

With this method you basically teletransport the GameObject, not taking in account 
    physics nor colliders. This one is pretty expensive if you have a RigidBody attached.

**AddForce:**

With this one you are adding force to the RigidBody of the GameObject, so all the 
    movement will be taking physics and colliders into account.

If you need to move a RigidBody (like a Player) I recommend using [MovePosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html).
It's more precise than AddForce and use the physics motor.

**EDIT:**

Example:

```
public float movementSpeed= 5f; //for instance

void FixedUpdate()
{

    Vector3 direction = new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), 0 , Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
    rigidbody.MovePosition(transform.position + direction * movementSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
}
```

Tweak movementSpeed to go faster or slower.

Didn't test the code but it should work.

Comment: ,,, I want to move player using keys in unity, MovePosition will be good for that? because i have tried using it, but my player straight away moves to the specified vector3 position. So MovePosition is simply used to move the object to a specified position, right?

Comment: @DavinderSingh yes. `MovePosition` moves your object to the specified position. If you are trying to move your player object, but do not want to hassle around with Rigidbodys, you could use a [CharacterController](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.html). Maybe this works better for you.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you don't want to use physics in your game cause it uses a lot of calculating power, also there are a lot of other use cases that the developer does not need to use physics to move the object or the collision with other objects is not important.